# Axios error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: typescript, api, axios

I'm getting that error submitting a request using Axios.

```js
    let getConfig = {
        headers: {'PTToken': 'token'},
        params: {
            'filter-id': `${id}`
        }
      }
      try {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get('https://api.practitest.com/api/v2/projects/id/tests.json', getConfig);
        console.log('data', data, status)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
      }
```

I've read posts that suggested this as a resolution:

```js
    let getConfig = {
        headers: {'PTToken': 'token'},
        params: {
            'filter-id': `${id}`
        },
        httpsAgent : {
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
      }
      try {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get('https://api.practitest.com/api/v2/id/tests.json', getConfig);
        console.log('data', data, status)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
      }
```

That's not working because I don't think I have it set up correctly.
Does anyone know how to configure an Axios request to ignore those ssl errors when sending post and get requests?